# Finding the length of a semi-ellipse (Calculus)

Tags: calculus, conic-sections, area, word-problem, arc-length

A fireplace is to be constructed in the shape of a semi-ellipse (half of the ellipse). The opening is to have a height of 2 feet at the center and a width of 5 feet along the base. The contractor who has been hired to construct the fireplace wants to draw an outline of the shape on the wall using thumb tacks and a string. Where should the tacks be placed and what should be the length of the string?

I believe I need to use arc length for the string length, but I don't know how to go about it exactly.

Comment: Recall that an ellipse is the set of all points such that the sum of the distances from the points to two particular points (called the foci) is constant. So the foci should be the tack locations, and the string length should be that constant sum. You can look at the wiki to figure out the right formula for your given axes lengths.

Comment: Contrary to the circle, the computation of the arc length of an ellipse is a difficult problem, which you cannot solve with the basic tools of calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Using for example the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) article on ellipses, you will find that the semi-major axis is $2.5$ feet and the semi-minor axis is $2$ feet. This means the foci are at $\pm 1.5$ feet, i.e.the tacks should be placed at the base, $1.5$ feet to either side of the center. The string should be $5$ feet long.